# macdeployqt - "file not found" - missing qml file from qrc

Tags: macos, qt, qml, macdeployqt

I am trying to deploy an app using Qt (version 5.6.1) for OS X (10.11.5) with macdeployqt tool. Just after running qmake and make the app seems to work fine. However, when I try to use macdeployqt I am experiencing some errors. The qml files become nonexistent, and I get following result:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/main.qml:-1 File not found
```

I've tried to run macdeployqt from its directory (as some people on the web suggested) and even tried some funky build of this tool provided by third party... I am aware of macqtdeploy `qmldir` option (it didn't change anything). Does anybody know what exactly macdeployqt is doing to those resources? Why they are missing?

Comment: Please add `qDebug() << QFile::exists(":/qml/main.qml")` in your main.cpp before loading it to check if the file exists. This will help to find the error.